# Quick way of finding the eigenvalues of circulant matrices over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, finite-fields, circulant-matrices

Is there a fast way to find eigenvalues of a circulant matrix over finite field?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues) gives a simple formula for the eigenvalues in terms of the entries of the top row of the circulant matrix. The same formula works over finite fields if (for an $n\times n$ circulant matrix) you replace $e^{2\pi i/n}$ with any $n^{th}$ root of unity over the finite field, i.e. any solution of $x^n=1$ with $x\in\mathbb F_q$.

Comment: This is a good start. I want to add that there a few subtleties in the case when $n$ is divisible by the characteristic. For then the desired roots of unity won't exist. Not even in an extension field. Consequently a circulant matrix is not always diagonalizable. The simplest example is
$$\pmatrix{0&1\cr 1&0\cr}$$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: @pre-kidney thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If the root of unity is in an extension field, can we still proceed with the formula? and do you meant that if the root does not exists even in the extension field, then the matrix must not be diagonalizable. thanks.

Comment: @AndyKang If the roots of unity are in an extension field, then, yes, the formula for the eigenvalues still works (they may also be in the extension field). Much the same way as the eigenvalues of a circulant real matrix may be complex. If the roots of unity don't exist even in an extension field, then the matrix need not be diagonalizable, but it still may be. In addition to the example three comments up you can also think of the $2\times2$ identity matrix over $\Bbb{F}_2$ :-)